# C# function updating arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, function

after I run function "left", I expect it to make changes to the relevant arrays, using array "D" as example. but within the "left" function, D is changed. however outside of it, it is not. please help explain why thanks. Excerpt of code below:

I can't post the code because of some error.

please see in link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/It5OfH

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int[][] transpose(int[][] A, string D)
    {
        int[][] B = new int[3][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            B[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (D == "CW")
                {
                    B[i][j] = A[2 - j][i];
                }
                else if (D == "CCW")
                {
                    B[i][j] = A[j][i];
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Direction input ERROR");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return B;
    }

    public static void front(int[][] F, int[][] L, int[][] U, int[][] R, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] F_ = new int[3][];
        int[] U_ = new int[]{L[2][2], L[1][2], L[0][2]};
        int[] R_ = new int[]{U[2][0], U[2][1], U[2][2]};
        int[] D_ = new int[]{R[0][0], R[1][0], R[2][0]};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            F_[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            L[i][2] = D[0][2 - i];
            U[2][i] = U_[i];
            R[i][0] = R_[i];
            D[0][i] = D_[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                F_[i][j] = F[2 - j][i];
            }
        }

        Array.Copy(F_, F, F.Length);
    }

    public static void left(int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] U, int[][] F, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(U, "CCW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(D, "CCW");
        front(L, B, U_, F, D_);
        U = transpose(U_, "CW");
        D = transpose(D_, "CW");
        print(D);
    }

    public static void back(int[][] B, int[][] R, int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(transpose(U, "CW"), "CW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(transpose(D, "CW"), "CW");
        front(B, R, U_, L, D_);
        U_ = transpose(transpose(U_, "CW"), "CW");
        D_ = transpose(transpose(D_, "CW"), "CW");
        Array.Copy(U_, U, U.Length);
        Array.Copy(D_, D, D.Length);
    }

    public static void right(int[][] R, int[][] F, int[][] U, int[][] B, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(U, "CW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(D, "CW");
        front(R, F, U_, B, D_);
        U_ = transpose(U_, "CCW");
        D_ = transpose(D_, "CCW");
        Array.Copy(U_, U, U.Length);
        Array.Copy(D_, D, D.Length);
    }

    public static void up(int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] R, int[][] F)
    {
        int[][] L_ = transpose(L, "CW");
        int[][] B_ = transpose(transpose(B, "CW"), "CW");
        int[][] R_ = transpose(R, "CCW");
        front(U, L_, B_, R_, F);
        L_ = transpose(L_, "CCW");
        B_ = transpose(transpose(B_, "CW"), "CW");
        R_ = transpose(R_, "CW");
        Array.Copy(L_, L, L.Length);
        Array.Copy(B_, B, B.Length);
        Array.Copy(R_, R, R.Length);
    }

    public static void down(int[][] D, int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] R, int[][] F)
    {
        int[][] L_ = transpose(L, "CCW");
        int[][] B_ = transpose(transpose(B, "CW"), "CW");
        int[][] R_ = transpose(R, "CW");
        front(D, L_, B_, R_, F);
        L_ = transpose(L_, "CW");
        B_ = transpose(transpose(B_, "CW"), "CW");
        R_ = transpose(R_, "CCW");
        Array.Copy(L_, L, L.Length);
        Array.Copy(B_, B, B.Length);
        Array.Copy(R_, R, R.Length);
    }

    public static void action(string[] input, int[][] F, int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] R, int[][] D, int[][] B)
    {
        foreach (string s in input)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
                case "F":
                    front(F, L, U, R, D);
                    break;
                case "L":
                    left(L, B, U, F, D);
                    break;
                case "B":
                    back(B, R, U, L, D);
                    break;
                case "R":
                    right(R, F, U, B, D);
                    break;
                case "U":
                    up(U, L, B, R, F);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    down(D, L, B, R, F);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Input error");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void final(int[][] F, int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] R, int[][] D, int[][] B)
    {
        string[] ans = new string[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (F[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[F[i][j] - 1] = "F";
                }

                if (L[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[L[i][j] - 1] = "L";
                }

                if (B[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[B[i][j] - 1] = "B";
                }

                if (R[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[R[i][j] - 1] = "R";
                }

                if (U[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[U[i][j] - 1] = "U";
                }

                if (D[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[D[i][j] - 1] = "D";
                }
            }
        }

        //***** Print Ans *****
        foreach (string a in ans)
        {
            Console.Write(a + " ");
        }
    //*********************
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        //********** initiate **********
        int[][] F = new int[3][];
        int[][] U = new int[3][];
        int[][] L = new int[3][];
        int[][] R = new int[3][];
        int[][] D = new int[3][];
        int[][] B = new int[3][];
        int x = 1;
        for (int i = F.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            U[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            L[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            R[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            D[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            B[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            F[i] = new int[]{x, x + 1, x + 2};
            x += 3;
        }

        //******************************
        //***** input data *****
        string ins = "L U F B B";
        string[] input = ins.Split(' ');
        //**********************
        //***** ACTION *****
        //action(input, F, U, L, R, D, B);
        //******************
        //***** Find Location *****
        //final(F, U, L, R, D, B);
        //*************************
        left(L, B, U, F, D);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(D);
        /*Console.WriteLine();
        print(F);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(L);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(B);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(R);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(U);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(D);*/
    }

    public static void print(int[][] S)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < S.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < S[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(S[i][j] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Your methods seem to create new arrays, but don't take their arguments by reference. So those new arrays are lost.

Comment: Do you only have this problem with the left function or do you have it by all of them (front, right, etc)?

Comment: the problem happens with all the functions (F, R, etc)

Comment: As @JeremyLakeman mentioned try [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword.

Comment: @Eldar  can you show an example of how's that done? thanks

Comment: It should look like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nYfp4f)

Comment: please don´t add your entire code here, just as much as needed to reproduce your issue. Probably that´s why you aren´t able to post the code here.

Comment: Thank you all problem resolved with the "ref" thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
    public static void left(int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] U, int[][] F, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(U, "CCW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(D, "CCW");
        front(L, B, U_, F, D_);
        U = transpose(U_, "CW");
        D = transpose(D_, "CW");
        print(D);
    }
```

Those assignments to U and D, are assignments to local variables. They won't cause any change to the variables copied from the caller. I suspect what you intended was;

```cs
    public static void left(int[][] L, int[][] B, ref int[][] U, int[][] F, ref int[][] D)
```

This forces the caller to provide a variable, which will be updated when the method returns.

Comment: very strange is, for example for the "front" function, the relevant arrays are all updated. why is that so but not that way for the "left" function. this was what got me stuck.

Answer (score 1):

pass D array as ref parameter will solve your issue

I have update code at below [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C2t0EK)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static int[][] transpose(int[][] A, string D)
    {
        int[][] B = new int[3][];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            B[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (D == "CW")
                {
                    B[i][j] = A[2 - j][i];
                }
                else if (D == "CCW")
                {
                    B[i][j] = A[j][i];
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Direction input ERROR");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return B;
    }

    public static void front(int[][] F, int[][] L, int[][] U, int[][] R, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] F_ = new int[3][];
        int[] U_ = new int[]{L[2][2], L[1][2], L[0][2]};
        int[] R_ = new int[]{U[2][0], U[2][1], U[2][2]};
        int[] D_ = new int[]{R[0][0], R[1][0], R[2][0]};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            F_[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            L[i][2] = D[0][2 - i];
            U[2][i] = U_[i];
            R[i][0] = R_[i];
            D[0][i] = D_[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                F_[i][j] = F[2 - j][i];
            }
        }

        Array.Copy(F_, F, F.Length);
    }

    public static void left(int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] U, int[][] F, ref int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(U, "CCW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(D, "CCW");
        front(L, B, U_, F, D_);
        U = transpose(U_, "CW");
        D = transpose(D_, "CW");
        print(D);
    }

    public static void back(int[][] B, int[][] R, int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(transpose(U, "CW"), "CW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(transpose(D, "CW"), "CW");
        front(B, R, U_, L, D_);
        U_ = transpose(transpose(U_, "CW"), "CW");
        D_ = transpose(transpose(D_, "CW"), "CW");
        Array.Copy(U_, U, U.Length);
        Array.Copy(D_, D, D.Length);
    }

    public static void right(int[][] R, int[][] F, int[][] U, int[][] B, int[][] D)
    {
        int[][] U_ = transpose(U, "CW");
        int[][] D_ = transpose(D, "CW");
        front(R, F, U_, B, D_);
        U_ = transpose(U_, "CCW");
        D_ = transpose(D_, "CCW");
        Array.Copy(U_, U, U.Length);
        Array.Copy(D_, D, D.Length);
    }

    public static void up(int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] R, int[][] F)
    {
        int[][] L_ = transpose(L, "CW");
        int[][] B_ = transpose(transpose(B, "CW"), "CW");
        int[][] R_ = transpose(R, "CCW");
        front(U, L_, B_, R_, F);
        L_ = transpose(L_, "CCW");
        B_ = transpose(transpose(B_, "CW"), "CW");
        R_ = transpose(R_, "CW");
        Array.Copy(L_, L, L.Length);
        Array.Copy(B_, B, B.Length);
        Array.Copy(R_, R, R.Length);
    }

    public static void down(int[][] D, int[][] L, int[][] B, int[][] R, int[][] F)
    {
        int[][] L_ = transpose(L, "CCW");
        int[][] B_ = transpose(transpose(B, "CW"), "CW");
        int[][] R_ = transpose(R, "CW");
        front(D, L_, B_, R_, F);
        L_ = transpose(L_, "CW");
        B_ = transpose(transpose(B_, "CW"), "CW");
        R_ = transpose(R_, "CCW");
        Array.Copy(L_, L, L.Length);
        Array.Copy(B_, B, B.Length);
        Array.Copy(R_, R, R.Length);
    }

    public static void action(string[] input, int[][] F, int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] R, int[][] D, int[][] B)
    {
        foreach (string s in input)
        {
            switch (s)
            {
                case "F":
                    front(F, L, U, R, D);
                    break;
                case "L":
                    left(L, B, U, F, ref D);
                    break;
                case "B":
                    back(B, R, U, L, D);
                    break;
                case "R":
                    right(R, F, U, B, D);
                    break;
                case "U":
                    up(U, L, B, R, F);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    down(D, L, B, R, F);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Input error");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void final(int[][] F, int[][] U, int[][] L, int[][] R, int[][] D, int[][] B)
    {
        string[] ans = new string[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (F[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[F[i][j] - 1] = "F";
                }

                if (L[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[L[i][j] - 1] = "L";
                }

                if (B[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[B[i][j] - 1] = "B";
                }

                if (R[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[R[i][j] - 1] = "R";
                }

                if (U[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[U[i][j] - 1] = "U";
                }

                if (D[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    ans[D[i][j] - 1] = "D";
                }
            }
        }

        //***** Print Ans *****
        foreach (string a in ans)
        {
            Console.Write(a + " ");
        }
    //*********************
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        //********** initiate **********
        int[][] F = new int[3][];
        int[][] U = new int[3][];
        int[][] L = new int[3][];
        int[][] R = new int[3][];
        int[][] D = new int[3][];
        int[][] B = new int[3][];
        int x = 1;
        for (int i = F.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            U[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            L[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            R[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            D[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            B[i] = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            F[i] = new int[]{x, x + 1, x + 2};
            x += 3;
        }

        //******************************
        //***** input data *****
        string ins = "L U F B B";
        string[] input = ins.Split(' ');
        //**********************
        //***** ACTION *****
        //action(input, F, U, L, R, D, B);
        //******************
        //***** Find Location *****
        //final(F, U, L, R, D, B);
        //*************************
        left(L, B, U, F, ref D);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(D);
        /*Console.WriteLine();
        print(F);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(L);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(B);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(R);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(U);
        Console.WriteLine();
        print(D);*/
    }

    public static void print(int[][] S)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < S.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < S[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(S[i][j] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is it that the "front" function doesnt need to put ref on all the parameters, but they update anyway?

Answer (score 0):

How about returning the array from left function. instead of void, return the modified array from where it is being called.

or we can use [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) while passing array. like this. `void Method(ref int refArgument)`. it will modify the original array. so you need not to return anything.

[learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/…](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) see this link

Comment: I'll have to return multiple arrays then, meaning I need to return into an array? so it'll be an array of a jagged array?

Comment: You should have one array that goes through multiple iterations, changing each time until the final function.

Comment: or we can use ref keyword while passing array. like this. void Method(ref int refArgument). it will modify the original array. so you need not to return anything.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref
see this link